# Derivation of the Backpropagation Algorithm for Neural Networks

Tags: algorithm, backpropagation

Perhaps this is a dumb question, but this doubt is really prohibiting me from understanding Backpropagation.
So I was reading and trying to understand the  [Backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Backpropagation#Learning_as_an_optimization_problem) Wikipedia article. It states that the discrepancy is `E=(t-y)^2`, and then:

> However, the output of a neuron depends on the weighted sum of all its inputs:
>
> `y=x1w1 + x2w2`

Shouldn't `y=phi(x1w1 + x2w2)` ?

And if `y = phi(x1w1 + x2w2)` isn't the plot of the discrepancy vs the weights supposed to be kind of a step function with one segment of weights returning the minimum and the rest not (because some combination of weights returns `0` and the other `1`, and only one of these answers is correct)

Comment: There is a `Derivation` section, which goes into a lot of detail. That part just gives you the intuition, for which it is irrelevant if it's `phi(...)` or just `...`. I can't explain it better than that, but I remember reading something along the lines of "backpropagation basically means <<keep doing the chain rule for derivatives>>" once (I forgot who said it and where - it might have been on another SO question). That made a lot of sense to me, at least intuitively. Maybe it will help you too!

Comment: i read the `Derivation` part but the part i asked is not making sense so i'm not sure whether i'm understanding everything correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand why you thought that, *but 'y' is the input sum and the output only depends on it*, if you wanna find the output, it's very simple, you just need apply it by the activation function phi, in this case I think we should use the phi because logistic function (the sigmoid curve) make things easier to understand when we plot a graphic that represent something that changes over time.

So let's take a look at the fuction you are talking about, y=phi(x1w1 + x2w2), we know that phi=1/(1+e^(-z)), so we can mix both equations to find the output(o): 
**o = 1/(1+e^(-(x1*w1+x2*w2)))**.

Perfect, now if you wanna discover if this is a step function, we can apply the some calculus and use the theorem of continuity.

The activation fuction is differentiable (it is a continues fuction) to make sure you can find the partial derivative of the error, if you need to. And knowing this, we can say that because the phi is continues and (x1*w1+x2*w2) is a polynomial function (also continues) that our final function 'o' it is a continues function.

Comment: "if you wanna find the output, it's very simple, you just need to multiply it by the activation function phi that will make things possible to find the derivative of the error"?
Why multiply? Shouldn't `y` become the argument of the sigmoid in this case? {i mean output = 1/[1+e^(-y)]}
And yes i studied calc

Comment: Sure, you need an activation fuction that is differentiable (it is a continues fuction) to make sure you can find the partial derivative of the error, if you need to. And knowing this, we can say that because the phi is continues and (x1*w1+x2*w2) is a polynomial function (also continues) that our final function y it is a continues function.

Comment: @minotaurus in this case I think we should use the phi because logistic function (the sigmoid curve) make things easier to understand when we plot a graphic that represent something that changes over time.

Comment: Ok so I'm stupid after all :P ... its now very clear what Wikipedia meant. It says the output **depends** on y=x1w1+x2w2, and then proceeds with the intuition. So my two mistakes were not reading the **depends** and looking in an intuition for rigorous mathematical derivation. Cheers and thanks.
Please update a little your answer so i can accept it

Comment: `we know that phi=1/(1+e^(-z)), so we can mix both equations: y=(x1*w1+x2*w2)/(1+e^(-z)).` ... this is wrong. I don't know how you got that, but that's wrong. `z` becomes `x1*w1+x2*w2` in `sigmoid(z)`. You don't multiply anything by the activation function at this stage, you apply the activation function to the weighted sum.

Comment: @IVlad I used the definition for each neuron, to find the output result. I thought that doing this I could prove that the plot of the fuction would not be a step fuction. But I got your point, you are telling me that z should become x1*w1+x2*w2 into the phi equation and now I saw my mistake, sorry for that, I will correct the anwser.